# Optimization formulas in LaTeX

Tags: equations

This is the code I'm using for my optimization problem.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rrclcl}
\displaystyle \min_{w,b,\xi} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\frac{1}{2}w^{t}w+C\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\xi_{i}}}\\
\textrm{s.t.} & y_{i}(w\phi(x_{i}+b))+\xi_{i}-1\\
&\xi\geq0    \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

This is the result:
[image]

I want third argument (`\xi\geq0`) under `yi`. How can I do that? How can I add `i=1` and `N` under and above summation?

Comment: Sorry. Third argument. I edited question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

this is very easy to accomplish using the `aligned` environment from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{w,b,\xi} \quad & \frac{1}{2}w^{t}w+C\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\xi_{i}}\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & y_{i}(w\phi(x_{i}+b))+\xi_{i}-1\\
  &\xi\geq0    \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: optput of example code]

(in the future, please make your code a full compilable example, from `\documentclass` through `\end{document}`.)

Comment: Thank you for answer and comment. How can I left hand side all the question block? It is more appropriate for optimization problems in articles.

Comment: the option `fleqn` applied to either the document class or to `amsmath` will shift the display blocks to the left.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is there a way to split the objective function up over multiple rows? I tried to do just this over three rows, and the vertical distance between the first and second row is much larger than that between the second and third row.

Answer (score 13):

An even easier approach would be to use the package optidef:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini*}|s|
{w,b,\xi}{\frac{1}{2}w^{t}w+C\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\xi_{i}}}
{}{}
\addConstraint{y_{i}(w\phi(x_{i}+b))+\xi_{i}-1}
\addConstraint{\xi\geq0}{}
\end{mini*}
\end{document}
```

and get the exactly same output:

[image]

The advantage of the package is that you can easily change the alignment of the constraints using four different formats, use a long format for the problem description, or add any referencing of your like. For example, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini!}|l|[3]
{w,b,\xi}{\frac{1}{2}w^{t}w+C\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\xi_{i}}}
{}{}
\addConstraint{y_{i}(w\phi(x_{i}+b))+\xi_{i}-1}
\addConstraint{\xi\geq0}{}
\end{mini!}
\end{document}
```

would produce three changes:

**1. A long format:** given by using `|l|` instead of `|s|`.

**2. Multiple referencing:** given by using  `\begin{mini!}` instead of `\begin{mini*}`.

**3. Put the constraints below the "subject to":**  given by using  `[3]` instead of default.

[image]

In addition, the package also provides other features like line breaking line, various ways of referencing equations, or other environments for defining maximizition or arg mini problems.

A post explaining more about the package can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19465/is-there-a-package-for-specifying-optimization-problems). The full documentation [here](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/optidef/optidef.pdf) and the repository with issue tracker [here](https://github.com/jeslago/optidef).

Comment: To clarify, "Multiple referencing" means the objective and constraints each get their own indices, for instance (1a), (1b), (1c).

Comment: This package has problem when constraints are long and need to break.

Comment: @G.T. The constraint can be split in multiple lines to avoid going beyond the margin. See https://github.com/jeslago/optidef/issues/26

Answer (score 4):

The `align` environment from `amsmath` also helps you achieve this with ease, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
& \min_{w,b,\xi} & & \frac{1}{2}w^{t}w+C\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\xi_{i}} \nonumber \\
& \textrm{s.t.} & & y_{i}(w\phi(x_{i}+b))+\xi_{i}-1 \label{opt_prob:misc} \tag{42}\\
& & & \xi\geq0 \nonumber \\
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

The important thing to note is that in the `align` environment, the alignment switches between left aligned and right aligned for consecutive columns. Therefore, I simply added an empty column to change the alignment of the expressions to left aligned.

Furthermore, while working in a jupyter notebook I found that `align` lets me use labels with the equations, unlike the `aligned` environment. This is the reason I prefer `align` over the other.

Edit: You can use the same script in markdown cells in Jupyter notebooks, except that you only need to include the part between the align statements.

Comment: Wow! I wasn't aware that you can align more than one element in the align environment but it seems (from the double &) that you can! Thanks for the info!