# How do I wrap a line inside a formula?

Tags: equations

My codes are

```
\begin{equation}\label{CSprogram}
 min||\sigma||_1\\
  subject to Tr(\omega_a\sigma)=Tr(\omega_a\rho) \forall \omega_a\in \Omega
\end{equation}
```

and I get (All the letters are crowded together):

[image]

But I want to get
[image]

Comment: `{equation}` does not support line breaks. But for this kind of stuff you should better look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235382/82917 anyway.

Comment: Thanks, got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gather` environment from `amsmath`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    \min{\lVert\sigma \rVert}_{1} \nonumber \\
    \textrm{subject to}\ \mathrm{Tr}(\omega_{a}\sigma) = \mathrm{Tr}(\omega_{a}\rho)
    \qquad \forall \quad \omega_{a} \in \Omega
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

---

Update.
In situations when one prefers to tag the whole expression spanning multiple lines, the `gathered` environment can be used instead

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
    \min{\lVert\sigma \rVert}_{1} \\
    \textrm{subject to}\ \mathrm{Tr}(\omega_{a}\sigma) = \mathrm{Tr}(\omega_{a}\rho)
    \qquad \forall \quad \omega_{a} \in \Omega
  \end{gathered}  
  \label{eq:example}
\end{equation}

Reference equation: \ref{eq:example}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the equation number really belongs to both lines, an alternate formulation is `\begin{equation} \begin{gathered} ... \end{gathered} \end{equation}`.  It's always useful to remember the "subsidiary" formulations of the multi-line environments.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for pointing this out. I updated the answer to cover the alternative approach.