# Writing optimization formulas in Tex

Tags: equations

I want argument (U,\Sigma ,V^{T}) under `min`
How can I draw that? An example is the equation in the following picture:

[image]

source: http://www.mmds.org/mmds/v2.1/ch09-recsys2.pdf

> MWE:

```
\begin{equation}
    \min_{U,\Sigma ,V^{T}} \sum_{(ij)\in A} (A_{ij} -[U \Sigma V^{T}]_{ij})^2 
\end{equation}
```

> I also tried this but it did not work:

```
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\begin{mini*}
    {U \Sigma V^{T}}{\sum (r_{ui} -[U \Sigma V^{T}]_{ui})^2}
    {}{}
    \addConstraint{}{}
\end{mini*}
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19465/is-there-a-package-for-specifying-optimization-problems

Comment: What's the problem? I see only that A is used with two contradictory meanings.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to get matrices `U,V,\Sigma` under `min`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @egreg has already pointed out in a comment, it seems weird (and is probably wrong) to write `ij\in A`.

I would say that the main issue is whether you can assume that your readers understand which range of numbers the row and column indices, `i` and `j`, may occupy, or if it's necessary to state these ranges explicitly. If it's the latter, it must be a good idea to use two summation symbols rather than just one.

[image]

(The matrices `A` and `U\Sigma V^T` are square, right?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\min_{U,V,\Sigma} \sum_{i,j} \bigl(A_{ij}-[U\Sigma V^T]_{ij}\bigr)^2\\
\min_{U,V,\Sigma} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \bigl(A_{ij}-[U\Sigma V^T]_{ij}\bigr)^2
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, check the updated OP

Comment: @Mico [off-topic] SVD can also be used with non-square matrices ;)

Comment: @Raaja - That’s why I asked whether it’s ok to assume that the readers can be assumed to know the ranges of the summation indices. :-)

Comment: @Mico Check a new comment in the OP

Comment: It is a matter of taste. I wanted to know how to write that equation. The set is fully specified in my thesis. People should not care about the content, whether it is right or not, this is not [https://math.stackexchange.com/]. We do not take care of that. Only the desired output.

Comment: @naveganTeX - I will definitely not discuss matters of taste with you.

Comment: @Mico Yes I did!

Comment: @Mico I didn't quite get that point ;) now clear.